# Is the dating of Anakin's fall and redemption/death relative to his age intentional?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, george-lucas, anakin-skywalker

Anakin was born in 41.9 BBY. He had his 10th birthday a few days after Ep I ended, and 20th birthday a day before Ep II started. Moving forward, he fell to the dark side at the age of 23, and was redeemed and subsequently died 23 years later, at 46.

Is this intended by design, in and out of universe, that he spent 23 years in the light and 23 years in the darkness? By the right of the G, by the will of the Force, was Anakin Skywalker specifically meant to live a life of balance - one part light, equal part dark - or is this just coincidence?

Comment: You could argue he spent only 13 years in the light, aka as a Jedi

Comment: Wow.You'd almost think the whole thing was explicitly *written* and not just some documentary about someone's life.

Comment: Over the years, I've read everything I could find of George Lucas discussing in his own words the symbolic elements he injected into Star Wars, and I don't recall number symbolism ever coming up (OTOH, this is stuff I read decades ago, so maybe I just forgot).

Comment: @DavidH well I didn't put any significance on the number 23, but on the fact that the length of his life spent before and after falling into darkness is almost identically long.

Comment: @thegreatjedi I think the significance, if there is any, has more to do with the mirroring of events in Anakin's life with those of Luke at a similar age. The rebirth of the Jedi upon the completion of Luke's training comes, ultimately, at the cost of Vader's life. This is paralleled in the prequels by Luke's conception being the pivotal event causing Anakin's fall to the dark side.

Comment: @phantom42-Could you pass the sarcasm, please?

Comment: I don't think that you'll find anything regarding that... Lucas himself is very cryptic and I think that he would be the only one to pick up on that anyway.